# Function uses and is part of map (circular dependency?)

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, circular-dependency

I'm writing a mini-shell thing for fun, and I'm trying to define a map of commands where one of the commands is `help`. `help` should print all available commands, and I (try to) do this by looping through the keys of the `commands` map, but since `help` is part of it, no matter which order I define them in, I always get a `Use of undeclared variable`-warning.
How do I solve this?

```
(def commands {:help help})

(defn help []
  (echo! "The available commands are:")
  (doseq [available-command (keys commands)]
    (echo! (name available-command))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
(declare help)
```

at the beginning.

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thank you!